# Replace Na based on condition

Tags: r

```
id var1 var2 var3 var4
1  3     5    NA    10
2  0     NA    7   NA
3  1      3    NA   6 
4  0     NA   NA    6
```

Hello I have this example as a data set. I am trying to replace the na based on the condition that if var1 =0 then replace all nas of the row as 0, but not the other na of the other rows.
I have tried the following

```
mydf <- replace(mydf, is.na(mydf), 0)
```

but as you understand this replaces all na values
I want to replace all nas of the row based on my condition not just for one column.
Could you provide me with some help please? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may create a condition with the var1 column as well to only consider those rows where 'var1' is 0

```
i1 <- is.na(mydf[-c(1, 2)])
i2 <- (mydf$var1 == 0)[row(mydf[-c(1,2)])]
mydf[-c(1,2)][i1 & i2] <- 0
```

-output

```
> mydf
  id var1 var2 var3 var4
1  1    3    5   NA   10
2  2    0    0    7    0
3  3    1    3   NA    6
4  4    0    0    0    6
```

---

Or instead of subsetting the data, it can be applied to the whole data as well

```
replace(mydf, is.na(mydf) & mydf$var1 == 0, 0)
  id var1 var2 var3 var4
1  1    3    5   NA   10
2  2    0    0    7    0
3  3    1    3   NA    6
4  4    0    0    0    6
```

---

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
mydf %>% 
   mutate(across(var2:var4, ~ replace(.x, is.na(.x) & var1 == 0, 0)))
```

-output

```
  id var1 var2 var3 var4
1  1    3    5   NA   10
2  2    0    0    7    0
3  3    1    3   NA    6
4  4    0    0    0    6
```

#### data

```
mydf <- structure(list(id = 1:4, var1 = c(3L, 0L, 1L, 0L), var2 = c(5L, 
NA, 3L, NA), var3 = c(NA, 7L, NA, NA), var4 = c(10L, NA, 6L, 
6L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```